# couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, androidx

To solve this error I have added following to app gradle file, Can somebody help me to understand that what is this error about? I am new to android

```
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);
if (useIntlJsc) {
        implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'
    } else {
        implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermesvm/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
```

PS: this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25415) is still open from facebook's react-native community

Comment: I also encountered this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258550/couldnt-find-dso-to-load-libhermes-executor-release-so